# Grub Refuses New Kernel

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, grub2

so my Mint 17 hasn't been booting, and I tried reinstalling the kernel from a live USB drive.

I followed the steps detailed in this [guide](http://statusq.org/archives/2012/10/24/4584/) to edit /etc/default/grub to accept the last saved kernel (while mounting the Mint partition and chrooting), but after updating grub, it still recognizes the older version (3.13.0-24-generic) instead of the new (3.13.0-55-generic) when the old version is no longer on my computer.

I'm not sure if this matters, but my grub starts in recovery mode. Using set prefix, set root, insmod, normal, I get back to normal grub 2.02. The one difference I notice is my /boot/grub folder is mostly empty, so while most people type set prefix=(hdx,y)/boot/grub, I type set prefix=(hdx,y)/boot/grub.bak. The system also starts off saying normal.mod is missing from /boot/grub. Would relocating some files help with the kernel or is it ok that I start in rescue grub?

Thanks for any help anybody can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell grub what default kernel to use in grub.conf. For mint, may be something like 'set default="0".

For the linux types I have used, the very top entry in the grub.conf is entry 0. So if you had three kernels listed, and you want to boot on the 3rd one, use 'default=2' or for mint, maybe 'set default=2'.

This link may or may not be useful: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/910

Comment: Went looking for my grub.conf file and actually found two. The grub/grub.bak was messing things up. The grub cfg was booting 3.13.0-55 while the grub.bak cfg was booting 3.13.0-24. Deleted the grub.bak and moved the others over and fixed it. Thanks for the help!